# Selfie camera using raspberry Pi

Tags: camera

I am a newbie. Thinking of the below project for fun. Looking for advice and the stuff I need to accomplish this:

A) the Pi will have a camera and a screen when I stand in front of it I can see my reflection just like I get when taking selfie with a phone.

B) the camera module can be activated by pressing a button in a remote control.

Is it too ambitious? What is the feasibility of this what is the best approach with cheapest devices I can use?

Comment: This is Q&A forum and not a blog to discuss your project. I suggest you to get the devices and components form WWW and then ask specific questions. Thanks!!

Comment: @qwerty there is a question around what modules/parts to use. Please understand I am a newbie.

Comment: Please take the tour: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour Ask about specific problems. Explain what you tried. Explain ho the result differed from what you expected.

Comment: As per the [help center](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) shopping recommendations are off-topic.  Distributors and manufacturers already advertise on the web; their information is not hard to find.  If you have a specific question about a specific device and its compatibility, feel free to ask that.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a place to just post your ideas. But making this would be relativly easy. You would need:

A pi-camera (its easy to use and well integrated)
Ada fruit 5-inch display (or like an old TV, or monitor of something)
Tactile push switch (or an old tv remote, for tv remote you will need an IR reciever)
Some male to female and male to male header leads
A breadboard